# Borrar contenido de un EditText según el texto que contenga

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi `EditText` quede en blanco al hacer `click` sobre él, pero solo si este contiene su texto inicial. Para ello, he tratado de hacer esto en el `OnClick`:

```
 if((editT.getText().toString()).equals(R.string.text3))
   {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "borrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      editT.setText("");
   }
```

No obstante, la condición del `if` no parece ser válida, ya que cuando lo uso no aparece el `Toast`, pero tanto este como la línea  `EditT.setText("");` funcionan sin el `if`. ¿Qué problema hay en la condición? He probado a no usar el `.toString()`pero sigue igual.

**EDIT**

Sigue surgiendo un problema y es que, pese a que con el `getString` funciona en Español, en Inglés se para la app aunque el @string usado sea el mismo pero en otro idioma.

Comment: `R.string.text3` contiene el valor inicial del `EditT` que intentas limpiar?  has probado a poner logs para ver por qué ese `if` no está entrando? Un saludo

Comment: Prueba ha hacer el equals con un literal en vez de usar `R.string.text3` usa  `"textoInicial"`. Intenta pasar el debug analizando que pasos hace y porque no entra en el if

Comment: Tu EditText se llama EditT??? normalmente las variables se empiezan por minúscula (te lo comento porque es un "estandar" entre los programadores). Si paras la ejecución en el if, ¿qué valores tienen el EditText y R.string.text3?

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano acabo de editar la pregunta con tu recomendación. En cuanto a los valores iniciales, el EditText (esdit) tiene el texto que hay en R.string.text3.

Comment: @lois6b he puesto un toast en el else del if como prueba por lo que sé que va a esa parte y no a la que yo querría.

Comment: @Andoni Alda he probado a poner el texto literal y funciona correctamente, pero me gustaría que lo hiciera con la referencia al string por temas de higiene. ¿A qué se puede deber la diferencia entre el texto literal?

Comment: Pepito, es obvio que si en el if no entra, entra en el else. Asi que **haz un log o debug** para ver qué contiene esas dos variables que crees que son iguales y claramente no lo son. Es primordial que tú depures tus aplicaciones para aprender más de ellas y donde pueden fallar.

Comment: @lois6b en el logcat no me aparece nada aparentemente significativo. No obstante, he hecho 2 toast, uno con  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.text3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); y otro con  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ID.getText().toString()+"="+ R.string.text3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); lo curioso es que en el primero me aparece el texto inicial, pero en el segundo aparece "texto inicial"= 213096... ¿Por qué algunas veces me aparece una especie de código numérico y en otras el String?

Comment: @pepito no estas recogiendo el string, no estaria mal leerse la documentacion si tienes un fallo en especial, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: @pepito te he adjuntado una nueva respuesta con la edicion que has hecho

Comment: @pepito pero parace ser que eres un usuario perezoso que no quiere leer respuestas de mas de 10 lineas. Se ve que tienes ganas de aprender a programar, asi te va a ir de maravilla...

Comment: @AndoniAlda hice la configuración de Strings de la manera que indicas en la resuesta pero pese a ello pasa lo que indico en la edición.

Comment: Por ello, mientras sigo leyendo documentación online he preferido poner los valores literales hasta encontrar la solución concreta a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El código para obtener el **String**  es;

```
getResources().getString(R.string.text3)
```

Esa es la cadena de texto que contiene `"text3"`, puedes usarla para comparar los textos, quedando así;

```
 if((editT.getText().toString()).equals(getResources().getString(R.string.text3)))
  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "borrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        editT.setText("");
  }
```

También puedes separarlo con

```
Resources r = getResources();
```

y luego utilizar **r** para sacar el texto;

```
r.getString(R.string.text3);
```

Answer (score 7):

Tienes que recoger el string de `R.string.text3` tu método quedaría así:

```
if((editT.getText().toString()).equals(getString(R.string.text3))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "borrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    editT.setText("");
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: Antes de preguntar deberias intentar arreglar los problemas por ti mismo usando el `debug` y **documentandote** un poco, que parece que no has mostrado el mas mínimo esfuerzo en saber en que te falla.</sub>

### Edicion

Como mencionas que no te funciona el recurso de idiomas y veo que sigues sin hacer caso a los consejos de **leerte la documentación** te dejo la información directamente sacada a partir de la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

## Crear directorios de configuración regional y archivos de strings

Para agregar compatibilidad con más idiomas, crea directorios values adicionales dentro de res/ que incluyan un guión y el código de idioma ISO al final del nombre del directorio. Por ejemplo, values-es/ es el directorio que contiene recursos simples para las configuraciones regionales con el código de idioma “es”. 
Una vez que decidas los idiomas que admitirás, crea los subdirectorios de recursos y los archivos de recursos de strings. Por ejemplo:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

Agrega los valores de string para cada configuración regional en el archivo correspondiente.

En tiempo de ejecución, el sistema Android usa un conjunto correspondiente de recursos de string basado en la configuración regional actual del dispositivo del usuario.

Por ejemplo, a continuación se indican algunos archivos diferentes de recursos de strings para distintos idiomas.

Inglés (configuración regional predeterminada), /values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Español, /values-es/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

## Usar los recursos de string

Puedes hacer referencia a tus recursos de string en el código fuente y en otros archivos XML usando el nombre del recurso definido por el atributo name del elemento .

En tu código fuente, puedes hacer referencia a un recurso de string con la sintaxis R.string.. Existen diferentes métodos disponibles que aceptan un recurso de string de esta manera.

Por ejemplo:

```
// Get a string resource from your app's Resources
String hello = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);

// Or supply a string resource to a method that requires a string
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(R.string.hello_world);
```

En otros archivos XML, puedes hacer referencia a un recurso de string con la sintaxis @string/ siempre que el atributo XML acepte un valor de string.

Por ejemplo:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```